# Write output of for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, output

I am trying to write each iterated output of for loop for further operations.
Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import io
from operator import itemgetter
with open('test.in') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [int(x) for x in content]
    content = tuple(content)
    nClus = input("Number of Clusters: ")
    nEig = input("Number of eigen values: ")
    j = 0
    k = nClus + 1
    content1 = ""
    for i in range(1,k):
        print content[j*(nEig+1):i*(nEig+1)]
        j = j + 1
```

The file test.in looks like this (which is an example, actual test.in contains huge amount of data)

```
40
1
4
3
5
7
29
6
9
4
7
3
50
1
2
3
4
5
57
9
8
7
6
5
```

The values nClus = 4, nEig = 5. 
Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: You've got a `print` statement inside your for loop, so that should do just fine in writing output. Is it not doing what you want? What is it doing, and what do you want it to be doing?

Comment: Tip: `for line in f` instead of eating away at your memory with `content = f.readlines()`

Comment: @Kevin I want to save each output to a variable, so that I can call anyone of them as required for my further operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just save them to an array (`mydata` below)?  I don't see where `j` stops (`other_dimension`, you can probably just delete it if you only have 1 dimension of results, I don't know your array size), but you can follow this format to get a numpy array to save data to:

```
import numpy as np
... [your code]
    mydata = np.zeros([k,other_dimension]) // other_dimension only if you are saving a rectangular matrix of results instead of a vector
    for i in range(1,k):
        mydata[row, column] = content[j*(nEig+1):i*(nEig+1)] // put your iterators here for row, column if applicable (rectangular matrix), otherwise mydata[iterator]
        print mydata[k, other_dimension] // other_dimension only if you are saving a rectangular matrix of results instead of a vector
        j = j + 1
```